# Forestplot package in R - add multiple confidence bands and text below x-axis

Tags: r, logistic-regression, r-forestplot

I'm using the forestplot package in R.

Example data:

```
library(forestplot)
library(tidyverse)

base_data <- tibble::tibble(mean  = c(0.578, 0.165, 0.246, 0.700, 0.348, 0.139, 1.017, 0.5),
                            lower = c(0.372, 0.018, 0.072, 0.333, 0.083, 0.016, 0.365, 0.2),
                            upper = c(0.898, 1.517, 0.833, 1.474, 1.455, 1.209, 2.831, 0.9),
                            study = c("Model 1, ITT", "Model 1, PP", "Model 2, ITT", "Model 2, PP",
                                      "Model 3, ITT", "Model 3, PP", "Model 4, ITT", "Model 4, PP"),
                            deaths_steroid = c("36", "1", "4", "14", "3", "1", "8", "9"),
                            deaths_placebo = c("60", "5", "11", "20", "7", "7", "10", "20"),
                            OR = c("0.58", "0.16", "0.25", "0.70", "0.35", "0.14", "1.02", "1.5"))


base_data %>%
  forestplot(labeltext = c(study, deaths_steroid, deaths_placebo, OR),
             clip = c(0.1, 2.5),
             xlog = TRUE)
```

I would like to have four rows, one for each model and within each have two confidence bands - one for ITT and one for PP with a legend displaying whether it is ITT or PP.

Also, is there an easy way to add e.g. "Higher in intervention/control group" below the x-axis?

Thanks, I'm quite new to R!

I have tried to find the answer but was unable to.